# How to record audio using matlab from IP android camera

Tags: android, matlab, url, save, audio-streaming

I am trying to save audio and image from android camera to my computer in the local network using IP webcam and Matlab.

The android application allows me to access different resources using featuring URL addresses:

- live streaming video: 192.168.0.105:8080/videofeed
- live streaming audio in wav: format 192.168.0.105:8080/audio.wav
- take one picture frame: 192.168.0.105:8080/shot.jpg

I have succeed to save images to matlab using this function  (it also displays images as video in real time):

```
function save_screen
url = 'http://192.168.0.105:8080/shot.jpg';
ss  = imread(url);
FileNum = 1;
fh = image(ss);
while(1)
    pause(1)
    ss  = imread(url);
    set(fh,'CData',ss);
    drawnow;
    fname = ['Image' num2str(FileNum) '.jpg'];
    imwrite(ss, fname, 'JPG');
    disp(['image saved ' fname]);
    FileNum = FileNum + 1;
end
```

Now, same as with images, I am trying  to  save audio from URL stream in sequences of 30 seconds  e.g. audio1, audio2, etc; in order to analyze it further in matlab. I have tried this with no success:

```
url = 'http://192.168.0.105:8080/audio.wav';
ss  = wavread(url);
FileNum2 = 1;
fh = wavread(ss);
while(1)
    pause(1)
    ss  = wavread(url);     
    wavwrite(ss,fname);
    disp(['Sacuvava se audio ' fname]);
    FileNum2 = FileNum2 + 1;
end
```

So to conclude, the main problem is to save 30 seconds audio sequences from URL. Any help highly appreciated

Comment: note: I have used pause(30) in second part of code. but I get this output: "??? Error using ==> wavread at 67
Cannot open file." And following also did not worked:
%sound(url)
y  = wavread(url);
while(1)
 y  = wavread(url);
 %extract 30 seconds into vector x.
 x = y([1:(30*Fs)]);
 wavwrite(x,Fs,'example.wav')
end